# Correctness of this Vector Inequality

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces, vectors

For scalars $a, b$ we know that $(a - b)^2 \ge 0 \implies 2a^2 + 2b^2 \ge (a+b)^2$
Is the analogous inequality for vectors also always true?
i.e., does $||\sum_{i}a_i||^2 \le 2\sum_i||a_i||^2$ ?

**Edit:**
We can show similarly for $2$ vectors that $||a+b||^2 \le 2||a||^2 + 2||b||^2$
Now, for $3$ vectors, we have $||a+b+c||^2 \le 2||a + b||^2 + 2||c||^2 \le  4||a||^2 + 4||b||^2 + 2||c||^2$

Is there a general form? like $||\sum_{i}a_i||^2 \le \alpha_i||a_i||^2$

Comment: It fails for  scalars also  if you have more than two terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is true is $\|\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i\|^{2} \leq n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \|a_i\|^{2}$. This follows from triangle inequality for the norm and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\|\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i\| \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \|a_i\|$; now use the inequality $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (1)(c_i))^{2} \leq (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} 1^{2})(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} c_i^{2})$ valid for scalars $c_i$.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on how it follows from the triangle and cauchy-schwarz inequalities?

Comment: @helperFunction I have edited my answer.